# A problem with instant preview in Lyx

Tags: lyx, preview

I have started using XYmatrix. it was recommended to me to enable instant preview. it worked great but now I see that it started to warp my previews. it "shrunk" them.

original:

[image]

preview:

[image]

did anyone see this problem before and know how to solve it?

edit:
it seems to happen only in inline formulas. In the display formula, it worked ok.
any ideas?

Comment: I have tried preview boxes but they don't really work for me. the stay as a box.

Comment: Please open a ticket with a minimal example file on https://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: it is a visual problem, not a code problem...

Comment: But to try to help, I have to try to see if I can reproduce the problem. To reproduce the problem, I need a minimal example. I do not see the problem for instant preview with my documents. The blue underline indicates you're using a non-default language. This could be the source of the problem but hard to tell without an example file.